# Using runt to do recurring non-weekly events in ruby (bi-weekly, every 3 weeks, etc)

Tags: ruby, schedule, recurring

I need to be able to create recurring events that happen on specific days but don't necessarily happen every week.  They could be scheduled bi-weekly, every 3 weeks, etc.  There is a current implementation that needs an update and I'd like to use the temporal expressions stuff from [runt](http://runt.rubyforge.org/) to redo it.

Runt will work for what I need except it doesn't seem to handle the intervals for non-weekly events.  It adds some complexity because the event also needs to capture a start date so you can accurately compute which weeks to fire the events and which to ignore them.  I think I can rework runt to do this, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if somebody has already tackled it, or there is a better solution out there.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to build what I needed into runt.  I've got the initial support already in (in the way of a REWeekWithIntervalTE class that takes a start date, interval, and weekday or array of weekdays).  If anybody is interested in playing with it you can check out my [fork](http://github.com/jwhitmire/runt).  Sorry for not being more clear in my initial question about it being a scheduling issue.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't clear, are you running a script continiously to do this?  If so why not use something like "at".

If this is a scheduling application have you looked at:
http://icalendar.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Sorry, you're right that was confusing.  I'm managing recurring scheduled events and need to know what days they should occur.  The idea being I have events that need to happen on Wednesday and Friday every other week, others that may happen every third Thursday, etc.

Comment: icalendar is great for exporting our events to a .ics file (which we already do), but not so much for handling the scheduling that needs to happen.